# Is the source code for the sfdx tools available?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Related to this question [How to handle the change to "Salesforce DX project format" and keep the revision history?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181463/how-to-handle-the-change-to-salesforce-dx-project-format-and-keep-the-revision), being able to see the source code for e.g.:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir <retrieve dir name>
```

would make it a lot easier to write a `git mv` equivalent.

Given the Node underpinnings, I thought I might just be able to see the implementation in the installed sfdx software but I can't find it even if it is there.

So my question is, is the source code for the sfdx tools available to build on when [writing your own sfdx plugin](http://www.wadewegner.com/2017/03/creating-a-plugin-for-the-sf-cli/)?

**PS**

May 2020 Salesforce blog post: [Open Sourcing Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/05/open-sourcing-salesforce-cli.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find GitHub Repo for Salesforce CLI source code
[here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforce-alm).

Salesforce open-sourced CLI, Check these blog posts [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/05/open-sourcing-salesforce-cli.html)

Update: Salesforce completely open sourced CLI, Now you can contribute to the Salesforce CLI repo, check the below blog post.

[Open Sourcing Salesforce CLI Update Feb. 2021](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/02/open-sourcing-salesforce-cli-update-feb-2021.html)

You can browse the Salesforce CLI GitHub organization [here](https://github.com/salesforcecli)

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Comment: @KeithC  For updates have a look at this blog post   https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/02/open-sourcing-salesforce-cli-update-feb-2021.html

Answer (score 3):

The source code is published to npm in the [salesforce-alm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/salesforce-alm) module.  There's no public repo for the code yet.

If you want to review the source for `sfdx force:mdapi:convert`, you can download the module from npm (e.g. `npm pack salesforce-alm`) or look at the version installed by `sfdx` (in `~/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm` on linux).

The `force:mdapi:convert` command is in `dist/commands/mdapi/mdapi_convert.js`, although the actual logic is in `dist/lib/mdapiConvertApi.js`.

You can use the node debugger with Chrome DevTools to step through the code.  Add a `debugger;` statement to `MdapiConvertCommand.execute`, for example, and start the node debugger:

```
~/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/node --inspect ~/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx.js force:mdapi:convert --rootdir src/
```

(The current version has source maps, but the code isn't minified.  You might need to delete all of the source maps to make the source readable, e.g. `find ~/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist -name \*.map | xargs rm`)

Comment: Sorry, xn. I felt obliged to make the (presumably recently published) repository link the accepted answer.

Comment: That's the best answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer for now is, "not *yet*".

The DX team have positioned themselves as pro open source and have discussed making some part of the CLI source code part of the OSS footprint of Salesforce in public presentations in the past. However, as of yet, there is not a public statement on a specific timeline for the roadmap for this or how much of it would be OSS (core engine, versus specific commands/modules, for instance).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify. Didn't want to be missing the opportunity of a better starting point just through not knowing.